# Best way to create these tables

Tags: database, normalization, database-normalization

I have the following situation.

We want an reputation table to evaluate Users And Companies.

This reputation table would store the reputation given by an Company to User and vice-versa.

It was suggested that we should create two reputation tables, one for the Users and another for the Companies, both with the same columns.

I dont think thats the best way but I cant find another solution.

Is there any other way we could do that?

thx

Comment: A table of companies, a table of Users and a table for reputation, with some for of id for each User and Company, then a table for reputation which would just have an id and reputation maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have a table for the company containing a unique key for that Co. Same for the user.

I assume the relationship between Co and User is many-to-many.

You need one more table containing both keys, for Co and User, and two fields, one for Co-rep and one for User-rep. The Co-key and User-key combination would be unique entries for this table.

Comment: We have discussed the solutions proposed and we sticked to that one.
thx!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your approach is bad; another solution would be to have an abstract `Entity` table, with each `User` and `Company` having its own `Entity` record (and thus entity ID); then you only track reputation between two entities in a single `Reputation` table.

Another approach is to have a `Reputation` table with a user ID, a company ID, and a `type` (or `direction`, or whatever seems logical in your model) field which indicates whether it is reputation for the company given by the user, or the other way around. Seems less normalized though.